# Is there a security-related motivation for prompting me for my email address, and then my email and password?

Tags: authentication, user-interface

Often when I am signing into web sites, I am prompted for credentials in two steps. First, they ask me to enter my email address. I type it in and click a button. Then they ask me for my password. I type it in and click a button. (Sometimes, as on a site I just visited, the email is displayed again, as if I might need to correct it. So in effect I have typed in my email address in order to access a form that needs my email address and password.)

From a simple design perspective I can't think of a good motivation for this practice. (The number of people who are confused by having two form fields to fill out is probably higher than I would guess, but it can't be *that* high.) Is there some security-related explanation for this?

Comment: Some sites like those from Google run JavaScript based Captcha test in background. Usually those tests are getting better the more interaction they get. And last but not least there are sites just copying this behavior from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Websites which employ this pattern usually allow users to set preferences for how they would like to authenticate. In addition to password, there might be authentication via cellphone message, via certificate, via oAuth through a 3rd party, via smartcard etc.

But you don't know how a user prefers to authenticate before you know their name. So you first ask for the account name and then you show them the UI for the preferred authentication method of that account.

Comment: The site I was on today (collegeboard.org) didn't have any alternative sign-on options. Do you suppose they're just adopting a practice seen from other sites then?